# POSIX sockets: Accepting connections with different transport protocols?

Tags: sockets, unix, posix, protocols, transport

I'm wondering what is the minimum required overhead in terms of the number of listening ports / server sockets required for accepting say N different connections, each using a different transport protocol that runs on top of IP, e.g. TCP, SCTP, DCCP, UDP etc.

Of course, a straghtforward approach would be to have N independent server sockets (each created via a call to `socket()` with the appropriate `protocol` parameter), each listening on a unique port. However, implementing this approach in an application that uses multiple protocols simultaneously would be extremely inconvenient since a client would need to know multiple server ports. In addition, in a peer-to-peer application that peers only once for each protocol (with the same client), the fact that each of the N server sockets only accepts a single (client) connection looks like a huge overhead (N additional sockets are introduced purely for handling N "real" connections to a single peering client).

Is it possible to do better than that, e.g. by reducing the number of listening server sockets and/or listening on the same port?

(For simplicity, you can assume N=2, one connection is TCP and the other one is DCCP or UDP (please don't make assumptions on connectionless communication since DCCP is connection-oriented).)

EDIT: I'm not interested in N (client) connections whose file descriptors are returned by N calls to `accept`. The question is about the additional overhead to make those N connections possible (i.e. there has to be at least one additional server socket that listens for incoming connections).

Comment: Can't even imagine what purpose such a design could serve...

Comment: 'a client would need to know multiple server ports' - why?  It only needs to know the one for the service it wishes to use.

Comment: If you want to broadcast huge amount of data in a LAN application, for instance, using a protocol such as UDP would make sense, as far as you don't care about packet loss and reordering.

Comment: Why does each server need N sockets per client ? A server would just start N "server" socket, and create additional sockets as clients connect. Anyhow, the socket API requires you to create at least 1 socket per transport type, you cannot combine several transports in one socket.

Comment: @MartinJames: Suppose a client wants to establish both a TCP connection with the same server and also a DCCP/UDP/STCP connection with the same service. Of course, one approach would be to establish the former first, and let server send the port number for the other connection through the first connection. But can you do better than that?

Comment: @nos: Here I'm talking about server sockets, the ones that are actually listening. Of course, the client connections are only created via the `accept` call, which returns a file descriptor to the newly created client socket.

Comment: @leden Then I fail to see what you really are asking about. If you want clients to connect on N different arbitrary transports, the client creates as many sockets as it wants to connect. The server listens on N sockets with well defined port numbers. (Or you can, as you say, have only one well defined protocol/port, e.g. TCP, and create the others on demand, sending the port number back)

Comment: @nos: can we somehow avoid opening those N listening sockets or at least have them listen on the same port and somehow distinguish based on the protocol? That's what it's about - how to manage those with the least overhead...

Comment: @leden Ok. The answer is no. The socket API have no such concept.

Comment: @leden why do you think that sharing a socket handler while having anything else separated would reduce any overhead?..

Answer (score 1):

To sum up what's said in the comments above: Since in the

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
```

call we must specify the `protocol`, we cannot use one socket for multiple protocols. We also cannot portably write

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0);
```

see [SOCK_RAW Demystified](http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw).

Regarding using the same port with different sockets: the possibility for this varies by system; e. g. see HP-UX (`man 7f inet`):

```
  The local port address is selected from independent domains for TCP
  and UDP sockets.  This means that creating a TCP socket and binding it
  to local port number 10000, for example, does not interfere with
  creating a UDP socket and also binding it to local port number 10000
  at the same time.
```

vs. Linux (`man ip`):

```
  Only one IP socket may be bound to any given local (address, port) pair.
```